# Linear algebra - reflection matrix of vectors of the same length

Tags: matrices, vectors, reflection

I would appreciate a hint for a question I have been struggling with for the last couple of days.

Let $v, w \in R^2$, and assume $||v||=||w||$.

Prove that there is only one reflection matrix that fulfills $Av=w$.

I’ve been trying to use the fact that $u+v$ and $u-v$ are orthogonal because $<u+v, u-v> = 0$ since $v$ and $u$ are from the same length and then look at $A(v+w)$ but that did not lead me anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Indeed, $v+w$ and $v-w$ are orthogonal and non-zero, which means that they form a basis of $\Bbb R^2$. If it is known what a linear transformation does to each element of a basis, then the linear transformation is completely determined (i.e. there is only one possible matrix for the transformation).

Now, what should the reflection do to the vector $v+w$? What should the reflection do to $v-w$? Try to figure out how the line across which the transformation should reflect is related to $v+w$ or $v-w$.

Comment: To be honest I do not quite get it. Could you give me some further explanation please regarding the second part? I really do not see the how the line and these vectors are related

Comment: @GreekMustard It might help to look at a concrete example. If $v = (2,1)$ and $w = (2,-1)$, then which reflection transformation should we consider (i.e. across which line)? How do the vectors $v + w$ and $v-w$ relate to this line?

Comment: @GreekMustard Also in case this wasn't clear, it helps to actually draw out the example

Comment: @Greek That's correct. And, as you've said, $v-w$ is perpendicular, which means that it must be flipped by the transformation. So, if $T$ is the reflection transformation, then $T(v+w) = ???$ and $T(v - w) = ???$. Once you fill those blanks in, you'll have said what $T$ does to a basis of $\Bbb R^2$, which means that the matrix of $T$ is uniquely determined.

Comment: Is it also possible to use the fact that the eigenvalues of a reflection are 0 and 1 to associate each vector to the corresponding value from the transformation’s image?

Comment: The eigenvalues of a reflection are $-1$ and $1$. But yes, and indeed that is essentially the argument that I am outlining.

Comment: Sorry, mixed it up with a projection matrix :) Cool! I think I got it, thank you!

Comment: What happens if v+w = 0? For example if $v = (1,2), w=(-1,-2)$

Comment: Seems like the line is just $y=-x$ which is spanned by $(1,-1)$

Comment: That's a fair point; you should probably handle that case separately. In that case, you need the line of reflection to be perpendicular to $v$. Similarly, if $v = w$, then you can take the reflection through the axis parallel to $v$